# Flaky Hibernate session?

Tags: web-services, hibernate, ehcache

Hibernate throws this error on me sometimes: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session.

Now: I know, I know- it means that the entity that I'm operating on has become detached from the session, so it can't initialize any properties that are lazily loaded. However, the problem is not 100% reproducible. It never happens on fresh deploys, so we solve the problem (for a while at least) by restarting the tainted servers.

We do have an in-memory cache enabled, but I can't figure out how the caching could interact with the lazy loading to cause this problem. Furthermore, why would we never see this problem on fresh servers, only on servers that have been up for a while?

Comment: Is the in memory cache the hibernate caching or something different like a 3rd party implementation?

Comment: it's ehcache with hibernate's caching interface.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have the same problem as you described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LazyInitializationException like this is typically thrown when you are using an object from an old, stale hibernate session. Say, for example, you have two requests:

```
Object o = null;

Request 1:
Session s1 = ...;
o = s1.get(MyObject.class, myId);
s1.close();

Request 2:
o.getFoo().getBar(); //May throw a lazyinit exception
```

Here a LazyInitializationException will be thrown if o.foo.bar was not loaded in Request 1. You need to fix your code so that Request 2 gets a fresh session, with a fresh copy of the object. This kind of problem can be tricky to track down; check for objects which you hold onto between requests, when no request is being processed (I've found that jvisualvm or jprobe can be a boon). Often the source of the problem is not obvious; anonymous classes can cause a reference to be held, for example.

Comment: The request happens in a web-service method, so we're not holding onto anything between requests. Each request should be independent and identical.

Comment: I guess it's possible that there is some bug with the second-level caching; but, I would assume it's your app inadvertently holding onto something (or closing the session early), until you can prove otherwise. What's the stack trace look like?

Comment: Oh, I'm hoping that it's in my app somewhere! That would mean that I could fix it ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure that I can sanitize the stack trace in a useful way. Basically, we ask whether one collection of entities contains another collection (which is lazily loaded). 

It actually looks like it should cause an error everywhere- the method that's calling it is not @Transactional. But it only fails sometimes! argh.